# Using CURRENT_DATE in JPA with Hibernate as JPA-Provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

JPA defines CURRENT_DATE as function. When I use CURRENT_DATE in JPQL Statements the underlaying JPA-Provider Hibernate won't parse this an only accept current_date() to be independent from DBMS.

In my mind CURRENT_DATE should be implemented in EVERY JPA-Provider because this is a essentiel function in JPA. I think this is a bug in Hibernate.

Example:

```
SELECT o FROM Objects o WHERE o.validFrom < CURRENT_DATE
```

This statement works with MySQL as DBMS but fails mith MSSQL because CURRENT_DATE is not parsed by Hibernate and CURRENT_DATE is send to DBMS which MSSQL won't understand. With current_date() anything is ok but this is not plain JPQL.

Please give me some hints, if this is a Hibernate bug oder anything else.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT o FROM Objects o WHERE o.validFrom < ?

and set a java.util.Date parameter initialised to the current date?